# Use JavaScript to execute a URL, but do not open a new window or tab

Tags: javascript

How can I use JS to execute a URL, but not open a new window or tab?

Comment: I think "execute" may not mean to you what it does to me.  Perhaps check out [jQuery's load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method?

Comment: It is not clear at all what you want the end result to be.  Do you want to load a new page into the current window, load a new page into an iframe in the current document or load content from another site into a portion of the current page?  Or something else?  Please clarify so someone can help you.

Comment: Not clear at all. Please tell us what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JS to load a url in the current window.

```
window.location.assign("http://google.com")
```

For more information, take a look at 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Methods

Answer (score 0):

If you have an URL of js file and you want that content to be executed then you can directly append the script element to your page.

```
var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
script.onload = function(){
    // do something on script load
};
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

This is the best I can make sense of the question.